# Определение dns адресов у proxy c#

Tags: c#, proxy, dns

Можно ли получить список dns proxy не используя при этом браузер ? Желательно средствами c#?

Насколько я знаю, при использовании прокси с ним идут и dns адреса (тестил на firefox : настройки - дополнительное - сеть - настроить и ставим галочку "отправлять dns запросы через proxy..", если галочку не ставить, то зайдя на whoer мы увидим dns системы).